# Does SIunits package correctly manage the typography according to the language of document?

Tags: typography, babel, siunits

when I use `SIunits` with `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{book}` and `\usepackage[frenchb,french,francais]{babel}` as preamble, could I be sure the commands like `\kilo\meter` will be print as the french typography recommend it?

For example, french can require thin non-breaking space before the abbreviation of a unit. But could `SIunits` do that?

Comment: I don't know of a `SIunits` package. Do you mean [`SIstyle`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sistyle) or [`siunits`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunits)? In any way both have been superseded by [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and are no longer actively developed.

Comment: @cgnieder `SIunits` actually exists, contrary to `siunits`; on Windows the two names are interchangeable, but the official name is the former. You're right in saying it has been superseded by `siunitx` that has some support for language locales.

Comment: What are the recommendation about the appearance of `\kilo\meter` and in what do they differ from the ones issued by the Bureau International de Poids et Mésures?

Comment: @egreg now that you mention it I checked the file name... strange that CTAN has different spellings for `SIunits` but not for `SIstyle`...

Comment: @cgnieder Due to the vast diffusion of a case insensitive operating system, it has always been customary to name packages with lowercase letters, with just a few exceptions: `SIunits` was one, `sistyle` not, AFAIR.

Comment: `\usepackage[french]{babel}` is sufficient; the options `francais` and `frenchb` are synonyms for `french`.

Comment: @fauve In the CTAN you can find this disclaimer about the `siunits` package: _Note that the pack­age is now su­per­seded by siu­nitx; siu­nits has main­te­nance-only sup­port, now._ So perhaps you'll find better to move at `siunitx`.

Answer (score 4):

The `SIunits` package has no interaction with `babel` (apart from solving a quirk when the `italian` option to `babel` is loaded).

If you want a thin (unbreakable) space between the number and the unit, load the package with the `thinqspace` option:

```
\usepackage[thinspace,thinqspace]{SIunits}
```

The `thinspace` option will use a thin space as separator of groups of digits

By default the `thickqspace` and `thickspace` options are loaded.

---

You should look at the successor of `SIunits`, namely `siunitx`, which is much more powerful and customizable. It also sports a “locale” based interface. With the declaration

```
\sisetup{locale = FR}
```

you set things up for the French recommendation, but check if they are really obeyed; in case there are differences, customizing the behavior of `siunitx` is really simple.

Answer (score 1):

By default, in `siunitx`, the space between  number and unit is unbreakable, and its value is a thin unbreakable space (`\,`), as you can see from the documentation (§ 5.13):

[image]

The same (thin unbreakable space) is true for the `numprint` package.

Comment: this is for `siunitx`

Comment: @percusse: I meant the  thin unbreakable space. I'll make that clear.

Comment: I mean the question is about siunit`S` not siunit`X`

Comment: @percusse: I didn't even notice that point (thought the question was settled. Should I withdraw my answer? I feel like the table might be useful to novice users for this particular point, as the documentation is rather dense.

Comment: That's my table ;-)

Comment: @Joseph Wright: never said it was mine;o). Just mentioned it was not so easy to find in the doc.